# Error uploading product photo in admin panel

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

I am using version 4.0.1.1 in opencart admin panel, I get the following error when uploading products to my site. How can i solve it:

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: Unsupported marker type 0x8b in /home/u0875596/public_html/system/library/image.php on line 49Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): "/home/u0889596/public_html/image/catalog/8696540186179.jpg" is not a valid JPEG file in /home/u0889596/public_html/system/library/image.php on line 49TypeError: Cannot assign bool to property Opencart\System\Library\Image::$image of type object in /home/u0889596/public_html/system/library/image.php on line 49
```